# Any Editor for VoltDB

Tags: voltdb

Like SQL Server Management Studio in SQL Server, is there any editor available for VoltDB so that I can create or edit scripts? I tried in DBeaver, but I'm unable to see stored procedure script, after creation.

Answer (score 1):

I've made one web editor opensource if you want to try it.
https://github.com/aamadeo27/vsqle

Answer (score 0):

Since java procedures are loaded as compiled jar files into VoltDB, and are declared using the CREATE PROCEDURE ... FROM command, you can use any IDE or text editor you prefer. Currently, VoltDB does not store a copy of the original .java source for java procedures, only the compiled bytecode.

You can declare simple one-statement procedures in DDL using the CREATE PROCEDURE ... AS command. This can be done from the VMC web interface, and you can access the existing DDL source within VMC. However, this is schema browser and an interactive SQL command line interface, not really an "editor".

We are working on an Eclipse plug-in that will be able to apply procedure code changes to an external VoltDB instance, and do remote debugging. This will be in an upcoming release. This would be an optional convenience for Eclipse users.

Full disclosure: I work at VoltDB.